# Tool for determining which service is using all my CPU

Tags: services, task-manager, debug

I am wondering if a tool exists that can tell me which service is causing services.exe to use all CPU time. Basically a Task Manager for services.exe.

Does anybody know of such a tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say what version of Windows you're running but in Windows 7 the Resource Monitor's CPU tab will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Use Process Explorer. [See details in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/134570/how-to-identify-what-is-starting-a-process/134585#134585) to a related question.

Comment: I tried that and process explorer does show me that services.exe uses 50% (dual core system). But it does not show which exact service that has gone crazy (services.exe runs multiple services inside its process).

Comment: Or did I overlook something?