# Please help me find what is attempting to start Notepad.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows, rundll32.exe

Notepad gets started (but fails to run) a few times in a row. Then this stops. This is a fresh install of windows 7 x64. It might (just a thought) be related to a pending restart after a Windows update.

I ran [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), which is the [natural choice](https://superuser.com/questions/134570/how-to-identify-what-is-starting-a-process) to find out what's starting a process. It's rundll32.exe. I scanned both rundll32.exe and notepad.exe with MalwareBytes AM and MS Security Essentials, nothing came up.

Here's the [full dump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8M2G_l-f_g6RGxraEdndFBVbEk/edit?usp=sharing) to rundll32.exe.

**Is it really rundll32.exe starting notepad, and why would this be happening?**

Comment: notepad.exe is an executable. you should NEVER use rundll32 to run an executable. something is seriously wrong. how are you attempting to start it? is your shortcut malicious? what happens when you double click the exe in c:\windows ?

Comment: Have you tried SysInterals' (Microsoft) `Autoruns`?

Comment: What was the command line used to start Notepad?  (See in Process Explorer, double click on the process, on the "Image" tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears (unless I'm mistaken) that the command used to invoke `rundll32` is

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL
```

This command should normally start the control panel. You could begin by trying to run that command manually and see if that works, or fails and replicates the behavior that you're seeing currently.

Notepad seems to be started by the following command:

```
notepad.exe C:\Users\master\AppData\Local\Temp\6868.tmp
```

I can't immediately connect the dots and say *why* it' being started, and what 6868.tmp is supposed to contain. It might be the case that this somehow stems from an installation that wants to display a readme file.

I would look in that temp directory and see if I found a `6868.tmp` file which might have permissions such that notepad can't display it. If so, look at the file and figure out where it comes from.

I would search for `Control_RunDLL` and `6868.tmp` in the registry to see if you find any clues.

If this happens again, I would do a new dump and see if still tried to open 6868.tmp with Notepad, or a new, different file. If there's a new file, something must be generating it. If so, you might have luck running Process Monitor (note Process Explorer this time) and filter for events where `Path` begins with `C:\Users\master\AppData\Local\Temp\`. (And if needed, enable boot logging in the options menu.) This will hopefully give you a clue what, if anything, is creating the file.

And according to you environment variables, (availabl i the log) this is no longer a completely clean install. You have installed *some* applications.

No clear answeer, but some things you can try to hopefully track down what is happening.

Comment: That's great, thanks. It should be enough to find out exactly what's going on, next time it happens. The recommended command does start the CP and there is no 6868.tmp in the temp folder.

Comment: I forgot this: Maybe you have checked the command line for the `rundll32` process in Process Explorer (in particular the argument, which specifies which DLL is executed). Maybe the `rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL` string just happened to exist in the loaded DLL and wasn't actually the command used to invoke the `rundll32` process.