# Something is starting a new cmd.exe every few minutes with no parent process; what?

Tags: windows-10

Something is launching a `cmd.exe` as SYSTEM every few minutes, with no parent process. They consume roughly a megabyte of ram each (+-50k), but no cpu. The most recently launched one uses around 5MB of ram. How do I figure out what is launching them?

Process Explorer, as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/134585/80760), doesn't show me anything since none of the processes have a parent.

Comment: You could try using Process Monitor to see what is launching them and what the cmd apps are doing.

Comment: It could be a scheduled task, either Windows built-in or 3rd party. [Find If a Unknown Program Window That Opened and Closed Immediately Was a Scheduled Task](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-unknown-program-open-and-close-immediately/)

Comment: Please don't cross post. It resulted in your post being migrated and counted as a duplicate here.

Answer (score 1):

Hooked the executable to see from where it was called. CrashPlan is once again delivering a superior experience by crashing my computer. Can't believe I'm paying for it, this is like the 4th time so far they've had a bug that crashed my computer.

They're running a restart.bat which kills the daemon and restarts it, and then never exits. I've filed a ticket.